# Routing all traffic from an external machine to a proxy to a proxy

Tags: networking, iptables, proxy, linux-networking, transparent-proxy

May be there is a duplicated question but it seems no one do this scenario.

I have several machines in my network which are not using proxy to outbound.

I want to redirect all traffic, using route tables, to an appliance so that appliance ingests that clean traffic and send it to a proxy, or at least to a proxy socks.

I've seen that apparently it could be made using RedSocks, or maybe not. I'm not able to make it work or if it is possible.

Machine1,Machine2,Machine3--|no proxy traffic|-->appliance--|proxy traffic|--> proxy:1080

Those machines are not allow to have proxy in its configuration. That's why I am struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your title seems little confusing but what I understand that you simply need a Transparent Proxy. For this you can use [Squid Proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/) With setting up Squid transparent proxy server, we have a major advantage of not configuring proxy setting on every user's machine. Being transparent means that users will have no idea that there requests are being passed through a proxy server. Chances are that the application you are to filter is based on squid proxy as it is in itself quite capable in filtering traffic.

There are plenty of transparent proxy article if you look around, you may follow one which is suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep, sorry if it seems confusing.
But what I need is not for the last piece to be a transparent proxy, but to transform all traffic into proxy traffic

Comment: I suggest you to look closely into transparent proxy concept, it will route all to and fro traffic through proxy.